# Sequences Tending to Infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $a_n>0$ for all $n$ (where $n$ is a natural number) and the sequence $(b_n)$ tends to infinity. 
Is it true that the sequence $(a_nb_n)$ will also tend to infinity? 
Please prove this as well.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What have you tried? Adding some context to your question, such as things you have tried, background in solving these types of problems etc, will help you get better attention and answers.

Answer (score 1):

No, let $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n=n$. Then $b_n$ tends to infinity when $n \to \infty$ , but for all $n$ you have $a_nb_n=\frac{1}{n}\cdot n=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the problem in the sense that if $(b_n)$ tends to infinity, all we have to do (and we can for any $(b_n)$) is pick $(a_n)$ such that it tends to $0$ as fast or faster than $(b_n)$ tends to infinity.

So, let $a_i = \frac1{|b_i|}$, then $(a_nb_n)$ is bounded.